# Well formed XML and not empty self closed elements

Tags: xml, well-formed

Can a xml be well formed having not empty elements self closed?

Anything like this:

```
<team>Chicago Bulls<playerA/>23<playerB/>43</team>
```

instead of:

```
<team>Chicago Bulls<playerA>23</playerA><playerB>43</playerB></team>
```

Would it be well formed and where I could read about it? Mostly from w3c.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have `<playerA />`, but the semantic/content between your two XML fragments are different

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both of your examples are well-formed, but to precede a player number with a `player` element rather than place it in the contents of the `player` element would be a very poor design decision as it would fail to leverage the natural hierarchy that XML tools and developers would expect.

You can read more about well-formedness,

- [2.1 Well-Formed XML Documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed)
- [Is there any difference between 'valid xml' and 'well formed xml'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085)

but do not expect to see your point addressed explicitly because your question is less about well-formedness than it is about design.

---

### Historical Note

XML's predecessor, SGML, had a notion of [omitted end tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_omission), which might be related to the motivation for your question. Instead of as in your first example where you use self-closing tags (which produce empty elements, to be clear),

```
<team>Chicago Bulls<playerA/>23<playerB/>43</team>
```

the `playerA` and `playerB` elements could be defined to have an omitted end tags, allowing the following markup:

```
<team>Chicago Bulls<playerA>23<playerB>43</team>
```

Your self-closing `player` elements have been replaced by open tags with omitted end tags.  This would *not* be well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1):

The XML you show is well-formed, but there are no "non-empty self-closed elements". If we add some whitespace, we can show the relationships between nodes:

```
<team>
   Chicago Bulls
   <playerA/>
   23
   <playerB/>
   43
</team>
```

So, the `team` element has 5 child nodes:

1. A text node containing "Chicago Bulls"
2. An element called `playerA` with no attributes or content
3. A text node containing "23"
4. An element called `playerB` with no attributes or content
5. A text node containing "43"

No relationship between these nodes is represented, other than their order - in particular, the text "23" is not associated with either of the self-closing elements.

---

Another way to show this is to remember that `<foo/>` is just **a different way of writing** `<foo></foo>`, so we can also write this:

```
<team>Chicago Bulls<playerA></playerA>23<playerB></playerB>43</team>
```

---

In contrast, systematically adding whitespace to your second example would look like this:

```
<team>
    Chicago Bulls
    <playerA>
        23
    </playerA>
    <playerB>
       43
    </playerB>
</team>
```

In this case, the `teams` element has only three direct children:

1. A text node containing "Chicago Bulls"
2. An element called `playerA`, which contains a text node containing "23"
3. An element called `playerB`, which contains a text node containing "43"